# How execute procedure in trigget INSERT AFTER mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I found a lot questions here, for example:
[Execute procedure in a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709399/execute-procedure-in-a-trigger)

But can not post own comment here for specify some moments.

I have trigger **INSERT AFTER**, in phpmyadmin I wrote:

```
...

BEGIN
insert_log(1, :new.idArticle, :new.ArticleName, :new.ArticleTime, :new.ArticleCategory, :new.ArticleToUserID);
END
...
```

I get error:

> MySQL: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(1, :new.idArticle, :new.ArticleName,
>   :new.ArticleTime, :new.ArticleCategory, :n' at line 2

Can you advise me what is wrong?

Comment: I deleted symbol ":" and added `CALL` Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER your_trigger
AFTER INSERT
    ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
      insert_log(1, NEW.idArticle,  NEW.ArticleName, NEW.ArticleTime,  NEW.ArticleCategory,     NEW.ArticleToUserID);
END;
```

Also note, MySQL's documentation page titled, "[Trigger Syntax and Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)" states:

```
 Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns 
 in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL extensions to triggers; 
 they are not case sensitive.
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you. I have only one question. If I created **variable** `SET @type = (SELECT...)`How I must use this variable in query in Insert? Also params Procedure's

Comment: I believe you can use it using it's declaration: `type`. Check out these S.O answers for variable usages:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841455/declare-variable-mysql-trigger and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176763/how-to-declare-variable-in-trigger-and-use-it-with-mysql ; Please let me know if you have any questions!